# Красота(,) да и только!

Tags: пунктуация

Красота(,) да и только! Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Повтор темы http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/6792/пунктуация-смех-да-и-только

Answer (score 4):

ДА И ТОЛЬКО - присоединительная конструкция, обычно обособляется.

Сам того не осознавая, он старался выплыть и барахтался в бездушном океане, иногда мстя ему в меру своих сил. Ах, эта месть – игра, да и только. Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. Лень, да и только.(укороченное от : Лень, да и только лень, не что другое)Значение постоянства, настойчивости действия или его ограничения.

Однако в примерах из художественной литературы нередки случаи, когда оборот «да и только» не обособляется: «Сядем сюда, мать моя! – говорит одна. – Темень-то какая! Искушение да и только…» А. Чехов, В вагоне. Здесь происходит некоторое переосмысление - присоединительный оборот выполняет роль усилительной частицы, почти междометия."Красота да и  только" как раз такой случай.Запятая не нужна.
http://all_words.academic.ru/17218/%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE

Answer (score 0):

Указанная запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя в текстах часто встречается обособление  "да и только", правильнее было бы считать его устойчивым выражением и не обособлять.

Можно предположить, что постановку запятой пользователи связывают с речевой паузой, которая возможна в некоторых случаях, например: сказка да и только. Здесь ударение на первом слоге существительного определяет наличие такой паузы.

О грамматике. При отсутствии обособления "ДА И" - это сочетание частицы ДА и соединительного союза И.

Comment: Не всегда, всё зависит от значения, от контекста.1) Да чем она лучше? Что в ней такого? Красота, да и только (значение ограничения, а у другой ум, порядочность и пр.)2) Там просто чудесно, красота да и только!(усиление чувств, восхищение - значение междометия, слитное сочетание)

Comment: Само по себе "да и только" - лишь часть устойчивого выражения. Можно говорить об устойчивости кратких выражений (и об отсутствии в них запятой): "смех/цирк/беда/чудеса да и только", но не обо всех, так как не всегда возможно отсутствие паузы.
Что касается разграничения значений, оно не всегда четко просматривается: "Вот так история, смех да и только. Вот так история, смех, да и только". Потому постановка запятой и считается авторской.

Comment: Очень трудно отличить "усиление суждения" от "ограничения действия". "Смех да и только" - это один лишь смех, или ничего, кроме смеха, или очень много смеха?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна.

**ДА И ТОЛЬКО, частица** (в конце предложения или части сложного предложения)

Употребляется для указания на постоянство, настойчивость в каком-либо действии или ограничение действия чем-либо, а также для подчеркивания категоричности высказывания. **Отделяется запятой (реже – тире)** от предшествующей части предложения.

*Прошло еще с полчаса – не спится, да и только.* М. Салтыков-Щедрин, Современная идиллия. *Тут... вон... общину в коммуну перетолковали: сумасшествие, да и только!* Н. Лесков, Некуда. *А та отвернулась в сторону, да и только!* М. Горький, Макар Чудра. *Ах, эта месть – игра, да и только.* Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. *…Подарки подействовали только вполовину; она стала ласковее, доверчивее ― да и только; так что он решился на последнее средство.* М. Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени.

В художественной литературе встречаются примеры необособления частицы: *«Сядем сюда, мать моя! – говорит одна. – Темень-то какая! Искушение да и только...»* А. Чехов, В вагоне. *Что-то пульсирует в этой жилке еле слышно. Чудеса да и только.* Д. Гранин, Зубр.

Comment: Вы цитируете книгу  "Трудные случаи русской грамматики", но это ведь не официальная точка зрения и не словарь. Грамматика там не имеет строгого объяснения, варианты также. Что это за частица, которая обособляется в конце предложения (вид, значение)? И как объяснить, что иногда пауза явно отсутствует, а иногда также явно обозначается. Мне кажется, что это связано с разной фонетикой слов. В общем, эта тема требует доработки и объяснения, решение неоднозначное, что и отражается в текстах